# Generate P2SH bitcoin address from WIF in BitcoinJ Java

Tags: bitcoinj, p2sh, java

I'm trying to create P2SH-Segwit bitcoin address from the WIF private key. I'm using the **BitcoinJ library in Java**. See the following code.

```
String base58PrivateKeyString = "KyyJ5vVWjZck5nsAgDWvoN1u7Q8qp5FzE8WiCq97MbnRgdLesqJZ";

NetworkParameters params = MainNetParams.get();
ECKey key;

if (base58PrivateKeyString.length() == 51 || base58PrivateKeyString.length() == 52) {
DumpedPrivateKey dumpedPrivateKey = DumpedPrivateKey.fromBase58(params, base58PrivateKeyString);
            key = dumpedPrivateKey.getKey();
} else {
            BigInteger privKey = Base58.decodeToBigInteger(base58PrivateKeyString);
            key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privKey);
}
        
// Getting the public key
String pubKeyStr = key.getPublicKeyAsHex();
System.out.println("Public key is: " + pubKeyStr + "\n");
        
//Getting the P2SH address
List<ECKey> eckeyAList = new ArrayList<>();
eckeyAList.add(key);
Script redeemScript = ScriptBuilder.createRedeemScript(1, eckeyAList);
Script script = ScriptBuilder.createP2SHOutputScript(redeemScript);
byte[] scriptHash = ScriptPattern.extractHashFromP2SH(script);
LegacyAddress legacyAddress = LegacyAddress.fromScriptHash(params, scriptHash);
System.out.println("P2S address from the WIF pivate key is: " + legacyAddress.toString()); //3Az5wdibtPRGac41aGtyqzT1ejtobvb6qW
```

Its output public key is 03b5319c83adf4a2e274c37401623c7bf0ba453cee3e119f3bc2c523d27059b64f.
Its **output P2SH address is 3Az5wdibtPRGac41aGtyqzT1ejtobvb6qW** which is far different from the **correct P2SH address 38SGXvkMvq8Tsop8rFx2K4JnaFKYZkjd5z**.

If any of you know to rectifying the issue I'm happy to take your opinion.

Comment: You would need to lost a lot more details. How did you figure out the correct address for your same script?

Comment: There are online tools to generate from the base58 private key. Just googled it.